# PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128 encryption in nodejs

Tags: node.js, cryptography, cryptojs

I'm trying to encrypt a string using PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128 in nodejs, however I'm having a bit of trouble determining the correct way to do it.

Lots of documentation state I can use the crypto library, which when I try crypto.getCiphers() I see 'aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha256' is supported.

I've tried various tutorials, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-crypto-createcipheriv-method/ and such but I'm mainly hitting "Invalid key length" or "Invalid initialization vector" when I try to change the cipher type.

Could anyone point me to some documentation or code samples that may assist in achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128* and *aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha256* refer to different things.

Both encrypt with AES-128 in CBC mode, but the former uses a key derivation, the latter a MAC (more precisely an HMAC) for authentication.

Regarding NodeJS, the latter has apparently never worked reliably. In some versions exceptions are generated, in others no authentication is performed (i.e. the processing is functionally identical to AES-128-CBC), see [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43040). This is not surprising since OpenSSL only intends this to be used in the context of TLS, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73386073/9014097), which of course also applies to NodeJS as this is just an OpenSSL wrapper.

But since you are concerned with *PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128*, the *aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha256* issues are in the end not relevant.
 *PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128* uses PBKDF2 (HMAC/SHA256) as key derivation, which is supported by NodeJS.  A possible implementation that is functionally identical to *PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128* is:

```js
var crypto = require("crypto");

// Key derivation
var password = 'my passphrase';
var salt = crypto.randomBytes(16); // some random salt
var digest = 'sha256';
var length = 16;
var iterations = 10000; 
var key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, iterations, length, digest);

// Encryption
var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16); // some random iv
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('AES-128-CBC', key, iv); 
var encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);

// Output
console.log(salt.toString('base64'));       // d/Gg4rn0Gp3vG6kOhzbAgw==
console.log(iv.toString('base64'));         // x7wfJAveb6hLdO4xqgWGKw==
console.log(encrypted.toString('base64'));  // RbN0MsUxCOWgBYatSbh+OIWJi8Q4BuvaYi6zMxqERvTzGtkmD2O4cmc0uMsuq9Tf
```

The encryption with *PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128* gives the same ciphertext when applying the same parameters. This can be checked e.g. with Java and the SunJCE provider which supports *PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128* ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#algorithmparameters-algorithms)).

---

Edit:

From the linked Java code for decryption all important parameters can be extracted directly:

```js
var crypto = require("crypto");

// Input parameter (from the Java code for decryption)
var password = 'azerty34';
var salt = '12345678'; 
var digest = 'sha256';
var length = 16;
var iterations = 20; 
var iv = password.padEnd(16, '\0').substr(0, 16);
var plaintext = '"My53cr3t"';

// Key derivation
var key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, iterations, length, digest);

// Encryption
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('AES-128-CBC', key, iv); 
var encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);

// Output
console.log(encrypted.toString('base64'));  // bEimOZ7qSoAd1NvoTNypIA==
```

Note that the IV is equal to the password, but truncated if it is larger than 16 bytes or padded with 0x00 values at the end if it is shorter than 16 bytes (as is the case here).

The NodeJS code now returns the required ciphertext for the given input parameters.

Keep in mind that the static salt is a serious security risk.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this and report back. Appreciate this greatly.

Comment: i'll mark you correct, though I still have an issue where my encryption isn't being accepted as a password. I was given an example of '1111' being encrypted to 'ZrDGVdiIYC7g/NZfP1+qkw==' - is there a way to check if this code produces a similar/matching result? I realise it changes every time but I'm unsure how to test.

Comment: @NickTriantafillou - To be able to reproduce the result of *your* encryption, the remaining parameters (password, salt, iv, iteration count) must be known. So you would have to post more details about your encryption, preferably the code.

Comment: thank you, I think I'm almost there.. I've been given some code which is supposed to decrypt what i'm encrypting (and it works with the example I'm given), so I can test my result vs theirs. I'm still getting some kind of padding error trying to decrypt what I'm encrypting, does this code assist in figuring out what I'm missing, using your sample encryption code? https://gist.github.com/llaumgui/cfdacee2783c7654e40a8c92305c88b9

Comment: @NickTriantafillou - Yes, with the linked Java code the missing information can be determined, please see the edit section of my answer.

Comment: absolutely perfect. I was just missing that password.padEnd - everything works perfectly, I can't express how appreciative I am. thank you SO much!