# Dart: How to use the `AES-256-CBC` method in encrypt package?

Tags: php, dart, encryption, aes, dart-server

My PHP server uses the encrypt as follows.

```
openssl_encrypt('data', 'AES-256-CBC', '1234567890123456', 0, '1234567890123456')
```

the result is `adVh7c/vcyascTS0Z669IA==`.

My dart server uses [encrypt package](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) as follows.

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;
Encrypter(AES(encryptKey, mode: AESMode.cbc)).encrypt('data', iv: '1234567890123456').base64
final encrypt.Key encryptKey = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('1234567890123456');
       final encrypt.IV encryptIvKey = encrypt.IV.fromUtf8('1234567890123456');
       final encrypt.Encrypter encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(encryptKey, mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc));
       print(encrypter.encrypt('data', iv: encryptIvKey).base64);
```

The result is `KQjJ76efmVlgGKDsj6dCog==`.

These result values are different.
I saw the [cipher method of PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php). If I change the cipher method in the PHP server from

```
AES-256-CBC
```

to

```
aes-128-cbc // or aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha1, aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha256
```

The result will be `KQjJ76efmVlgGKDsj6dCog==`. (same as the result from the dart server)
But editing files in the PHP server is the last choice.
What I can do in the dart server to make the result the same as the result from the PHP server (`AES-256-CBC` method)?

How to use the `AES-256-CBC` method in [encrypt package](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt)?
If I must edit files in the PHP server, what method I should use?
The `aes-128-cbc`, `aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha1` and `aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha256` give the same result. Or some method better than this and it is available in [encrypt package](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) as follows in this image. Suggestion me, please.
[image]

Comment: `aes-256-cbc` requires a 32 bytes key. The key in the PHP code is too short and is *implicitly* padded with `0x00` values. In the Dart code this must be done *explicitly*, e.g. with `'1234567890123456'.padRight(32, '\x00')`.

Comment: Regarding `aes-128-cbc`, `aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha1` and `aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha256`: Apply `aes-128-cbc`, s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73386073/9014097).

Comment: Thank you too much. I never know about this. I only know the key in `encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('1234567890123456');` can be 16, 24, or 32 bytes but I never know that the cipher method requires n bytes. Do you want to add an answer to this? I will check for you.  Thank you for your new knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The summary from the comment in my post by @Topaco.
The `aes-256-cbc` cipher method requires a 32 bytes key.
Use the key with a string length of 32 or use the `padRight(32, '\x00')` function.

example:

```
final encrypt.Key encryptKey = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('1234567890123456'.padRight(32, '\x00'));
```

Regarding `aes-128-cbc`, `aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha1` and `aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha256`: Apply `aes-128-cbc`([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73386073/9014097))